# Django Rest Framework cannot add extra fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django. And I trying to work along with [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (DRF from now on) to create an API so I can consume it from a React frontend.

I am getting currently:

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `answers_set` on serializer `QuestionSerializer`.
>
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Question` instance.
>
> Original exception text was: 'Question' object has no attribute 'answers_set'.

But I have followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573102/how-do-i-include-related-model-fields-using-django-rest-framework) to add extra fields and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719776/django-rest-framwork-got-attributeerror-when-attempting-to-get-a-value-for-field) to dig into that error. Still getting the same error.

So, I have two models:

#### Question

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

#### Answer

```py
class Answer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

So I have two serializers:

#### AnswerSerializer

```py
class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['answer', 'created_by', 'updated_at']
```

#### QuestionSerializer

```py
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers_set = AnswerSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'answers_set',
            'created_by',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ]
```

I guess this is the "relevant" information to get what I am doing wrong... So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `answer_set` not `answers_set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be **`answer_set`** instead of ***`answers_set`***

OR

set the **`source`** as

```
answers_set = AnswerSerializer(many=True, source="answer_set")
```

Comment: I thought `answers_set` was literal depending on the variable name, not a reserved word. Thank you.